# How to create hard to kill app/process in .net?

Tags: .net, security, process, kill

What is the best way to secure background process/service from killing? I consider creating 2 or 3 services which will watch each other and start when they are stopped.

Do you know a better way to achieve this?

Cheers!

Update:
There are some comments which says "dont do that". I don't want to harm a computer or make some kind or virus. There are some situations where you need to do such a thing eg. parental control. I know that operating systems are for users, but I would like to know the best possible way to secure process/service from killing.

Update2: There was a question about use case. The application should monitor and block unwanted websites on children computer. The children should be able to install/uninstall other software so it have to be administrator account.

Comment: don't. you shouldn't force people to have to go through hoops to kill your app. if it's important make it a service so that only users with the appropriate rights can start/stop it.

Comment: Right, **don't**. If your software is worth running, people will run it. If not, well, sorry. There's not much you can do. Operating systems are built for the *user*; there'll always be *some* way to kill your process.

Comment: I don't think this question deserves downvoting - it's not a bad question per se. The *intent* might be misguided, but if we can provide a useful alternative solution to the problem then this is a valuable question worth pursuing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can explain the use case? There is almost certainly a better solution than using the approach of a malware for any genuinely useful piece of functionality. Without knowing what you're attempting it's hard to advise.

**Edit**

You would be better off creating a windows service and instructing your parent to install as an administrator, with child accounts being denied permission to modify the service. That way your system administrators (parents) aren't deprived control over their own system.

Comment: The application should monitor and block unwanted websites on children computer. The children should be able to install/uninstall software so it have to be administrator account.

Comment: You should consider blocking sites on a proxy or router, not on a client computer. (Though it might require a small investment -- about $50. I'm going to take this approach when my kid grows enough, but I already have a router with parental control features.)

Comment: Good idea, but I think that it is too complicated for standard user (not a geek). It should be very simple - sit in front of children computer, fill wizard and... thats all, 2 minutes. Creating users and assigning rights is a rocket science for normal user I think.

Answer (score 0):

This could lead to bad behavior and may lead anyone who ran your application to get into safe mode and set the services to disabled upon startup.

It's best to let your users decide which services to run.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I can't leave this decision to the user. I have to secure it somehow.

Comment: The users will be in the age of 7-15 and may not know what is good for them.